# Flexbox not working for image's background

Tags: html, css, flexbox

It's my first post here. I need to center my background image horizontally and vertically in CSS,however whatever way I try the image stubbornly remains on its place. I've read like 30 posts on the issue, but nothing seems to work for me. Thank you for any suggestions

```css
.angryjalapeno {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(https://placehold.co/200x200);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="angryjalapeno"></div>
```

HTML version here

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Background as color and image</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

        <div class="angryjalapeno">


        </div>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your html please?

Comment: cleared the cache (`Ctrl + F5`)? Flexbox only align direct child elements not background-images.

Comment: Your code looks OK for centering the image while also covering its element. flex is not relevant to this. Please create a runnable snippet with an image we can see and check it definitely shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `background-size: cover` puts the image placeholder in the center of the `div`.

```css
.angryjalapeno {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(https://placehold.co/200x100);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    /* background-size: cover; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="angryjalapeno">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your picture is bigger than 300x500, then your code true. But if it's smaller than this size you need to remove `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score -2):

I recommend that you change your `background-position` property to something like this.

```css
background-position: center center;
```

Comment: `center` as single value is equal to `center center`. A single value addresses both vertical and horizontal axis.

Comment: See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position#values) - "*If only one value is specified, the second value is assumed to be center*"